# What does it mean and what are the reasons for when a RPi3 cannot find a service?

Tags: bluetooth, python-2.x

I have a RPi3 which can successfully trust, pair, connect and even list the service UUIDs of a BLE device both via bluetoothctl and via Bluepy python library.

But when it tries to 'get' that service with getServiceByUUID() it fails to find the service.

What could be the underlying reasons for such an error?

```
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line
> 449, in getServiceByUUID raise BTLEException(BTLEException.GATT_ERROR,
> "Service %s not found" % (uuid.getCommonName()))
> bluepy.btle.BTLEException: Service ffe0 not found
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50537310/rpi3-cant-find-ffe0-service-via-bluepy-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of inspecting the btle.py file, I noticed the getServices() function was not being called.  I added a call to it and now it find can find the service:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bluepy.btle as btle
p = btle.Peripheral("00:0E:0B:00:75:12", "random")
services=p.getServices()
for service in services:
   print service
s = p.getServiceByUUID("0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
c = s.getCharacteristics()[0]
c.write("e", "utf-8")
p.disconnect()
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.